# Grails ID (primary key) column as String

Tags: string, grails, primary-key, grails-orm, crud

I'm learning Grails and I have a question about legacy tables.  Right now I am using scaffolding in my controller, but will eventually (of course) build it out to a custom controller and views - right now I am just trying to get the model right.  Say that I have an existing  table FOOBAR, with the columns FOOBAR_CODE (varchar, primary key) and FOOBAR_DESC (varchar) - how can I model this (as in make a domain class, such that I can CRUD)?  I have scoured the internet to no avail - certainly I am just missing something.  Looking at examples, my last attempt is below.  When I visit the controller's "list" action I see a "Code" and "Desc" column, the "Desc" column has values in it but the "Code" column doesn't (I have my application hooked-up to an existing table with some rows in it) - so clearly my app isn't associating my "Code" property/column with the correct column (FOOBAR_CODE) - which is further evidenced by the fact that when when I try to add a new entry and I get the error "Field 'FOOBAR_CODE' doesn't have a default value" - the app isn't associating the "Desc" field on the create form with the FOOBAR_DESC column in the DB.  I am sure that my question will be answered in my future studies, I know I'm jumping the gun a bit.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

I am sure that one of my problems is the "generator: 'assigned'" - which seems to be relying on the DB to assign a value.

Basically, I have an existing table with two varchar columns (one is the primary key) and I am attempting CRUD capabilities.

I would greatly appreciate any insight!

Thanks!

```
class FOOBAR {

    String id
    String code
    String desc

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        table "FOOBAR"

        version false
        columns {
            id column: 'FOOBAR_CODE', generator: 'assigned', name: 'code'
            desc column: "FOOBAR_DESC"
        }
      }


}
```

Comment: Have a look into this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856336/changing-primary-key-id-to-string-type-in-grails/8860451#8860451

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class FOOBAR {

    String code
    String desc

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        table "FOOBAR" //schema: "SCHEMA" if it is different from the user

        version false
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'code'
        code column: "FOOBAR_CODE"
        desc column: "FOOBAR_DESC"
      }

}
```

Comment: Hi James,

Thank you very much for your response - I am still getting the "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value" error when trying to create a new record via the UI - and the error "FOOBAR not found with id null" when editing a record via the UI - any other suggestions?

Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: Post the table schema and the code that is producing the error.