# GRAILS After changing type of ID to 'int' I can not create objects any longer

Tags: grails, grails-orm, create-table

In our legacy system(MSSQL) we use int as the type of the id and I don't want to interfere with that so I change the type like this:

```
static mapping  = {
    id              column: "id",              type:        'int'
```

But then in the bootstrap where I create some sample records, it no longer works.
Error message:

```
Configuring Spring Security UI ...
... finished configuring Spring Security UI

2017-03-04 10:31:20.381 ERROR --- [           main] o.h.p.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl        : HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: com.buffer.ProdBuffer, setter method of property: id
2017-03-04 10:31:20.385 ERROR --- [           main] o.h.p.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl        : HHH000091: Expected type: java.lang.Long, actual value: java.lang.Integer
2017-03-04 10:31:20.419 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [com.buffer.ProdBuffer.id (expected type = java.lang.Long)]; target = [com.buffer.ProdBuffer : (unsaved)], property value = [1] setter of com.buffer.ProdBuffer.id; nested exception is IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [com.buffer.ProdBuffer.id (expected type = java.lang.Long)]; target = [com.buffer.ProdBuffer : (unsaved)], property value = [1]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:296)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertHibernateAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:661)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:247)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:187)
```

It look's like I missed something... do I need to do something more than just change the type in "static mapping" ?

A part of the class:

```
class ProdBuffer {
     String status
    String product
    String length
    int    productNo

    static mapping  = {
        table 'LOBuffertv2'
        id              column: "id",              type:        'integer'
        product     column: "Produkt",         sqltype: "char", length: 150
        length      column: "Length",          sqltype: "char", length: 25
        productNo       column: "ProductNo"
    }
    static constraints = {
        status(inList:["Preliminary","Activ","Finished","Cancelled"])
        status                  nullable: true
        product                 nullable: true
        length                  nullable: true
        productNo               nullable: true       
    }
}
```

Comment: try `id    column: "id",     type:        'integer'`

Comment: Read my answer how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to alter the tables in the DB to handle ids as BIGINT(20). And remove the id from domain class definitions and from mappings. Gorm will do the rest of job for you.

Comment: It's not that easy, a lot of program with thousands of db-accesspoints and hundreds of stored procedures using tables with id of type int. I wouldn't dare  changing them. In this case I'm working on is hopefully easier to manage but I know there will be more.

Comment: I have tried 'integer' instead of 'int' but it didn't change anything. Maybe I did something wrong then. I'll try it again.

Comment: @larand, please show a listing example of your domain class.

Comment: Ok, I added a part of the domain class. I debugged and stopped in the bootstrap so I could see the table structure created in the DB. This time it changed to 'int' but when the create and save executes I get the error listed above. I have another class where there is no such problem. I also skipped the bootstrap to see if I get the same failure when creating from the form. And so it was.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of the problem in this link:[Mapping ID to another type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856336/changing-primary-key-id-to-string-type-in-grails)

I just declared id in the class explicitly as an int.
As I could understand in the link, I even not need to declare the type in the mapping.

```
class PBuff {
    int id
    String sawMill
    String status
    String product
    String length

    static mapping  = {
          id column: 'id', type: 'integer'  
    }
    static constraints = {
        status(inList:["Preliminary","Activ","Finished","Cancelled"])

        sawMill                 nullable: true
        status                  nullable: true
        product                 nullable: true
        length                  nullable: true

    }

}
```